# Error in testing Promise with Mocha - 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, this

I keep getting the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined,' and I don't know why it's happening. Any thoughts?

```
describe('render fn', () => {
    it('should return a string', () => {
        let filename = __filename, 
            content = 'Hello, World', 
            theme = './test.less';
        return file.render(filename, content, theme)
            .then((css) => {
                expect(css).to.be.a('string');
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the code I'm trying to test:

```
render(filename, content, theme) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.config.renderOptions));

        if (theme)
            options.paths.push(path.resolve(this.config.theme.path, theme));

        options.paths.push(path.resolve(this.config[filename].resolve.root));

        less.render(content, options, (e, output) => {
            if (e != null) reject(e);
            resolve(output.css);
        });
    });
}
```

I've been working on this for a long time now, and I'd appreciate any help. 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `var path = require('path');` in that file with `render`?

Comment: `this.config[filename]` is undefined? The stack trace of the error will show the exact location of the error (line + offset).

Comment: Yes, I do have `var path = require('path');` at the top. Sorry for not including it earlier. The stack trace is telling me that the error is on the same line as the return statement in the test, at offset = 17, so the beginning of the params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I keep getting the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of
>   undefined,' and I don't know why it's happening. Any thoughts?

The problem lies in this line:

```
options.paths.push(path.resolve(this.config[filename].resolve.root));
```

where you try to read the property `.resolve` on the object `this.config[filename]`. The error message is telling you that the object is `undefined`. Your code is equal to:

```
var myObject = undefined;
console.log(myObject.resolve); //Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
```

I cannot tell from the code you have listed in your question why `this.config[filename]` is `undefined`.

Comment: The `this` refers to context in which `render()` is called, not the context of `path.resolve()`. Otherwise, refering to `this.config` would (probably) have already thrown an error.

Comment: @rabbitco Well answered! Thank you!

Comment: @robertklep: No. The Javascript interpreter divides the execution o a function into two phases: (1) Creation stage and (2) Execution stage. During the creation stage the interpreter amongst others creates the arguments, variables and functions of a function. As `path.resolve()` is passed as an argument to `options.paths.push()` this results in the execution of `path.resolve()` before the execution of  `options.paths.push()`, the anonymous `Promise` function and `render()`.

Comment: As you now the value of `this` is determined at runtime and since `path.resolve()` is executed first the value of `this` is determined by the callsite of `path.resolve()` which in this case is inside `options.paths.push()` and therefore the value of `this` defaults to the global object (aka `undefined`). I have revised my example in my answer above to further highlight this point.

Comment: @John.Blackstone: Np. It would be polite of you to check mark answer if it is of value to you so I can increase my reputation points :) TIA.

Comment: @rabbitco `this.config[filename]` is a variable, it will get evaluated before being passed to `path.resolve()`. There is no closure that could change the value of `this` to the context of `path.resolve()` ([demo](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/aaac774ca0e6d3b7c25a82b438e9333d)).

Comment: @robertklep: The Javascript interpreter creates the execution context *before* executing `path.resolve()`. Inside `path.resolve()` one of its parameters is initialized to the argument `this.config[filename]`. As the execution context of `path.resolve()` is inside another function the interpreter looks for `config` in the global scope and finds nothing (aka `undefined`). See my example in the answer above.

Comment: @rabbitco you're overthinking `this` (quite literally); `this.config[filename]` is simply undefined (as I already stated in my comment yesterday), but that has nothing to do at all with contexts, or binding, or whatever. Just a missing property in a config object.

Comment: @robertklep: you are right. Thank you for persisting. I have edited my answer which then in fact becomes your answer.